# Increasing input signal by 5V (Using 7805 voltage regulator)

Tags: voltage-regulator

I have an analog voltage input of 0-5V DC, and need a corresponding output of (IN + 5V) 5-10V.

My first thought is to use the +5V regulator to "step-up" the voltage directly, connecting the input to the ground of the regulator and using the regulator's output as my final output.

I have a +15V power rail that I'm using to power the 7805, but when I try to hook it up, the 7805 pulls its ground (the input) up to almost 10V. Is it bad form to use voltage regulators in series? I'm modeling my input using a variable PSU for now, so could it be a problem with current not allowed into the PSU?

UPDATE: The problem is definitely that the PSU will not accept back-current, as suggested in the answer by Oli Glaser below. I would love to use a voltage follower op-amp to buffer this current, but I don't know if I have/can obtain any op-amps that can survive that much current (I can't remember exactly how much, but I know I measured sink current in excess of 100mA when the regulator was connected directly to ground). Would a voltage follower transistor design be more robust in that way?

Comment: Can you show us your circuit please?

Comment: Sure -- what's the best method for me to draw it?

Comment: Any method that allows us to understand what you are describing

Comment: Please draw your schematic in any tool of your choice (paper napkins and pencils have been used more than once on this site), and upload the image to any public image hosting site. Then post the link to the image here as a comment, and someone with editing rights will incorporate the image into your question pretty quickly.

Comment: Your description does not make consistent sense. A FULL word description of what you are trying to do would be good. Vin range. Vout range. Why. Providing a circuit of what you are doing is a good idea BUT if we do not know what you are wanting the circuit to do the circuit diagram alone will not be enough. An LM317 will probably do what you want better. ||| I have a voltage source of xxx volts. I wish to obtain an output of yyy to zzz volts. I wish to vary the output by kkk. I ...

Comment: There's a schematic editor built-in to the site now, or at least it appears to me (in the set of icons above an edit window)

Comment: How can a regulator like the 7805 be a "step-up power source"?

Comment: @pjc50 you need atleast 10 rep to use it though, same as posting images. It's a spam prevention thing.

Comment: If the input voltage is only 5V (or less), that is not enough to operate a 7805. A 7805 is a part which is optimized to provide a reasonably accurate 5V with minimum external parts (just capacitors), and from some voltage that is higher than 5 by several volts. If you want a more accurate 5V, or variable voltage, or a custom voltage, then use an LM317 which is adjustable. To step a voltage up, you need a boost converter or voltage doubler. Or, if it is coming from a transformer+rectifier, design in a different transformer which doesn't drop down as much, then linearly regulate down from there.

Comment: Can you specify the nature of the input (impedance, current drive capability, speed of change) and likewise for the output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to adjust the output voltage of your 7805 regulator to output 5V - 10V by adjusting the voltage at it's ground pin between 0V and 5V.
If you are doing this, the pin needs to be able to sink current in order to maintain regulation, so whatever the power source used, it needs to be capable of this. Many supplies will only source current, and if this is the case what you are seeing will occur.

A simple resistor divider with potentiometer can be used, or an opamp to drive the 7805 ground pin is maybe the best solution, preferably with a output including its negative rail if you want to go all the way down to 5V. You will find many example adjustable supply circuits on the web, and in the datasheets of the regulators also.

Here are a couple of example circuits:

Pot adjust, from [this page](http://www.talkingelectronics.com/pay/BEC-3/Page57.html) with more info:

[image: Pot adjust]

Opamp adjust, from [datasheet](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/LM/LM7805.pdf) pg.24 (don't use a 741 if you can possibly avoid it, as they are obsolete):

[image: Opamp adjust]

Comment: Well done ! :-). Your interpretation makes good sense but escaped me. I can usually see what a question means and I'm surprised that I failed to in this case. Clearly, the smell of green = 6.

Comment: @Russell - :-) It puzzled me too for a while, but after a few reads through, I figured this was the most likely interpretation. Hopefully I was right, and the OP can confirm this or update the question as necessary.

Comment: Now that sir is true engineering! You found a solution that makes sense in a situation when the requestor didn't or couldn't state the problem clearly.

Comment: +1, and I don't even need to say why!

Comment: You've just about nailed it on the head, thank you. The problem was definitely the sink current on the PSU. I can't quite fix it in the way you explain, though. My control needs to be a voltage signal, not a physical control like a pot. I'll upload a better description (picture) of the problem once I get access to my library's scanner -- I don't have a camera.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure the op amp won't work in my case. I measured the sink current off of the ground pin of the 7805, and it was definitely exceeding 25mA.

Comment: If this is what is really wanted, you'd use something else, like LM317. LM7805 is optimized for situations when you want within a couple percent of five volts, with minimal part count.

Comment: @VruNix - Many opamps can sink more than 25mA, they are exactly what is required for such a task. Also as Kaz notes there are more suitable regulators than the 7805 to base such a design around. You may want to check out the excellent Lab Power Supply Design Series from Dave Jones over at EEVBlog, there are 12 episodes dedicated to designing an adjustable supply and the problems/theory surrounding it. Here is the [main page](http://www.eevblog.com/episodes/) and [episode 1](http://www.eevblog.com/2011/11/28/eevblog-221-lab-power-supply-design-part-1/).

Comment: Also, with proper design you shouldn't see such a large ground pin current anyway, >25mA sounds like something is not right.

Comment: After a lot more work, I've come to the realization (as have the rest of you) that this was not a good design in general. The application was powering a DC fan motor, so I ended up using PWM control instead of power-amplifying the signal. Your answer was still very helpful in banging out my confusion, and definitely answered my (incomplete) question. Hopefully someone else can benefit from my mistake.

Comment: @VruNix - Glad to hear you have a working circuit, PWM is perfect for this type of application, as the active element (e.g. power MOSFET or similar) is either fully on or off, not in between where it dissipates much more power (it is instructive to simulate both the analog and PWM circuits in SPICE and graph the transistor power dissipation for each) so you just have the device on impedance (usually a few tens of mOhm for a FET) and the short time in between on/off during switching to contribute to the device dissipation.